# using Provider from "react-redux" is not working, I am getting blank screen. One of the errors shows Invalid hook call

Tags: react-redux, react-hooks

This is the error:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of
> the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>    and fix this problem.
>    React 2
>    Provider Redux
>    React 17
>    js index.js:16
>    factory react refresh:6
>    Webpack 3 react.development.js:1476
>    React 2
>    Provider Redux
>    React 17
>    js index.js:16
>    factory react refresh:6
>    Webpack 3
>    **webpack_require**
>
>     The above error occurred in the  component:
>
> Provider@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:69100:15
>
> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error
> handling behavior.

> ```
> React 10
> unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:468
> React 9
> js index.js:16
> factory react refresh:6
> Webpack 3
> ```

This is from App.js

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Hello Ignite</h1>
        </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is from index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
//REDUX SETUP
import { createStore } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducers/index";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";


const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
```

This is from ./reducers/index

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import gamesReducer from "./gamesReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  games: gamesReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

This is from ./reducers/gamesReducer

```
const initState = {
    popular: [],
    newGames: [],
    upcoming: [],
    searched: [],
  };
  
  const gamesReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "FETCH_GAMES":
        return { ...state};
      default:
        return { ...state };
    }
  };
  
  export default gamesReducer;
```

This is from package json

```
{
  "name": "ignite",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is from node modules package json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "framer-motion": "^6.2.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```

I'm stuck in the beginning of project the moment App wrapped into Provider it is not rendering "Hello Ignite"
Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the code that you've posted which would cause that error.  Read up on the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) and see if you can find where  you are making that invalid hook call.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same challenge too recently. I installed the react-redux version 5 instead of the version 7 by running this command:

npm install react-redux@5

I hope this works for you too.